# Can only update a mounted or mounting component. due to Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, setstate

I want to write a musicplayer with react.js. After init works ths player well.

But once I change the site with router to music list, the console show me the error:

> Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means
>   you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the Player component

I have marked the line in code.

I think, while I am changing the site, the player component may be unmounted. But wihtout the `componentWillUnmount` function, nothing different.

[Here](https://github.com/LeMueller/musicplayer-by-react) is my project.

Thanks in advance!

player.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../../styles/player.less';
import Progress from '../commen/progress.js';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

let duration = null;

export default class Player extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            progress: 0,
            volume: 0,
            isPlay: true,
        },

        this.play=this.play.bind(this);
        this.progressChangeHandler=this.progressChangeHandler.bind(this);
        this.volumeChangeHandler=this.volumeChangeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        $('#player').bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate,(e)=>{
            duration = e.jPlayer.status.duration;//total duration of the song
            this.setState({//here is the problem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                volume: e.jPlayer.options.volume*100,
                progress:e.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute
            });//how lange already played
        });
    }

    componentWillUnMount(){
        //$('#player').unbind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate);
    }

    //从子组件中获得值
    //change progress
    progressChangeHandler(progress){

            $('#player').jPlayer('play', duration * progress); 

    }
    //change volume
    volumeChangeHandler(progress){
        $('#player').jPlayer('volume', progress);
    }

    //play pause switcher
    play(){
        if(this.state.isPlay){
            $('#player').jPlayer('pause');
        }else{
            $('#player').jPlayer('play');
        }

        this.setState({
            isPlay: !this.state.isPlay,
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="player-page">
                <h1 className="caption">
                    <Link to="/list">My Favorite Music</Link>
                </h1>
                <div className="mt20 row">
                    <div className = "controll-wrapper">
                        <h2 className="music-title">{this.props.currentMusicItem.title}</h2>
                        <h3 className="music-artist mt10">{this.props.currentMusicItem.artist}</h3>
                        <div className="row mt20">
                            <div className="left-time -col-auto">-2:00</div>
                            <div className="volume-container">
                                <i className="icon-volume rt"></i>
                                <div className="volume-wrapper">
                                    <Progress 
                                        progress={this.state.volume} 
                                        onProgressChange={this.volumeChangeHandler}
                                        barColor="#aaa"></Progress>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="progress-container">
                            <Progress 
                                progress={this.state.progress}
                                onProgressChange={this.progressChangeHandler}>
                            </Progress>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt35 row">
                            <div>
                                <i className="icon prev"></i>
                                <i className={`icon ml20 ${this.state.isPlay ? 'pause' : 'play'}`} onClick={this.play}></i>
                                <i className="icon next ml20"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="-col-auto">
                                <i className="icon repeat-cycle"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="-col-auto cover">
                        <img src={this.props.currentMusicItem.cover} alt={this.props.currentMusicItem.title}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            /**<div className="player-page">
                <Progress progress={this.state.progress} onProgressChange={this.progressChangeHandler}></Progress>
            </div>**/
        )
    }
}
```

root.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from './commen/header.js';
import Player from './page/player.js';
import {MUSIC_LIST} from '../config/musiclist';
import MusicListUI from './page/musiclistui.js';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


export default class Root extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            musiclist: MUSIC_LIST,
            currentMusicItem: MUSIC_LIST[0]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){


        $('#player').jPlayer({
            ready:function(){
                $(this).jPlayer('setMedia',{
                    mp3:'http://oj4t8z2d5.bkt.clouddn.com/%E9%AD%94%E9%AC%BC%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%A9%E4%BD%BF.mp3'
                }).jPlayer('play');
            },
            supplied:'mp3',
            wmode: 'window'
        });


    }


    render(){

        const Home=() => (
            <Player
                currentMusicItem={this.state.currentMusicItem}
            />
        );

        const List = () => (
            <MusicListUI
                currentMusicItem={this.state.currentMusicItem}
                musiclist={this.state.musiclist}
            />
        );

        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/list" component={List}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>   
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error sums it up well. When you change the route component gets unmounted and callback tries to `setState` on unmounted component. You have to figure out how to do clean up before this happens. I see you already figured out that you can use `componentWillUnmount`, but you have a typo:

```
componentWillUnMount(){  // should be componentWillUnmount!
    //$('#player').unbind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate);
}
```

Notice also that `bind` method has been deprecated.

Comment: be clear about the context of the `bind` method. another common `bind` comes from javascript which is still in use

Answer (score 1):

Router is not your issue. Your issue is that you are fighting a fundamental design paradigm of React... or perhaps common sense. You are not supposed to try and perform operations on components that don't currently don't exist. What would that accomplish? In your case, you have a bunch of event listeners that you haven't removed.

As a side note, you are using an incredible amount of jQuery. You should be using `this.setState` as often as you can. You're programming in a style that goes against some of the best aspects of React.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new in ReactJS, even JS. I write the project according to a tutorial to learn ReactJS. Maybe i should choose other tutorials. Do you have suggestions for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeMüller I'm afraid I don't. But I don't think this is a good app to get your feet wet in React. You should start with a smaller app that only uses React fundamentals. This is a very complex app that integrates many things all at once, which might be overwhelming for a user new to React.